# mysql results differ with brackets

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the IDs of students that got a lower percent than the lowest percent of a particular student (StuID = 1027, and I know their lowest mark is 33).
If I use the following command, I get a sizable number of results

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT STUID FROM uniData WHERE PERCENT < 33;
+-------+
| STUID |
+-------+
|  1001 |
|  1010 |
|  1012 |
|  1016 |
|  1017 |
|  1022 |
|  1032 |
|  1034 |
|  1045 |
|  1048 |
|  1055 |
+-------+
11 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

and if I want to find this particular student's lowest mark, I use the following code, with its result:

```
mysql> SELECT  MIN(PERCENT) FROM uniData WHERE STUID = 1027;
+--------------+
| MIN(PERCENT) |
+--------------+
| 33           |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, if I put this together, I only get one student ID selected:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT STUID FROM uniData WHERE PERCENT < (SELECT  MIN(PERCENT) FROM uniData WHERE STUID = 1027);
+-------+
| STUID |
+-------+
|  1055 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why does mysql interpret this differently? How should I modify my 3rd query, so that I get the same results as the first query?

It doesn't seem to matter if I use 'LIKE' or  '='. 
Removing DISTINCT doesn't seem to have an effect. 
Does the fact that it is the last StuID on the first list have something to do with it?

Comment: How is percent stored?  My first guess is that it is a numeric type with decimal points, so student 1027 could really have a value of `32.6`.

Comment: Why are you using Like instead of = ???

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
  SELECT STUID ,(SELECT  MIN(PERCENT) FROM uniData WHERE STUID LIKE '1027') as mins,
  PERCENT 
  FROM uniData 
  group by STUID
  having `PERCENT` < mins ;
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41c87/1)

Your query works good thought. [take a look here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41c87/2)

Comment: Unfortunately this returns an empty set

Comment: have you checked the demo ? how empty ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query. It may help you

```
SELECT a.* from(
   SELECT STUID,MIN(PERCENT)Percent FROM uniData 
   group by STUID
)a where a.Percent < 33;
```

Comment: This still only returns a single value

Answer (score -1):

you can use between

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUID FROM uniData WHERE PERCENT between(0,(SELECT  MIN(PERCENT) FROM uniData WHERE STUID LIKE '1027'))
```